# $locationProvider html5 mode enable/disable in controller?

Tags: angularjs

Basically I made an app for the whole website and different controller on each pages ( not all pages use angular but the page it do it have separate controller of its own ).

I *don't use* template routing. Its basic php html views but needed angular to control some functionality on each page.

**Problem :** Now on one page for sake of a pretty url I have to enable html5mode. But this disable navigation (native click and refresh) in other pages.

**Question :** 
1. Either Can i disable html5mode in others controller or enable only in that specific controller ?

2. Any other suggestion to solve the problem ?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do. Can you accomplish what you need to do without client side url templates? Since the $locationProvider service can be configured on a per module basis, might be able to do this by breaking your angular app into multiple modules and registering controllers accordingly, but I have never tried that.

Comment: Thanks @Aluan ..Yeah It sure will work by breaking it in multiple module, but thats the last option I want to do ( if it have any other way )